# Matplotlib does not correctly plot when high precision is required

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an x-grid with very little variation:

```
    xGrid =np.linspace(1-1e-14, 1-1e-16, 30, dtype=np.longdouble)
```

Indeed, `python` does register that these are different values, no rounding error so far:

```
np.diff(xGrid)
Out[3]: 
array([ 3.33066907387547e-16,  3.33066907387547e-16,  3.33066907387547e-16,
        3.33066907387547e-16,  3.33066907387547e-16,  3.33066907387547e-16,
        3.33066907387547e-16,  4.44089209850063e-16,  3.33066907387547e-16,
        3.33066907387547e-16,  3.33066907387547e-16,  3.33066907387547e-16,
        3.33066907387547e-16,  3.33066907387547e-16,  3.33066907387547e-16,
        3.33066907387547e-16,  3.33066907387547e-16,  3.33066907387547e-16,
        3.33066907387547e-16,  3.33066907387547e-16,  3.33066907387547e-16,
        4.44089209850063e-16,  3.33066907387547e-16,  3.33066907387547e-16,
        3.33066907387547e-16,  3.33066907387547e-16,  3.33066907387547e-16,
        3.33066907387547e-16,  3.33066907387547e-16], dtype=float128)
```

and corresponding results:

```
results
Out[4]: 
array([-0.008459815023688, -0.008459815023688, -0.008492385739403,
       -0.008492385739403, -0.008492385739403, -0.008524840401542,
       -0.008524840401542, -0.008524840401542, -0.008557185310022,
       -0.008557185310022, -0.008589426764757, -0.008589426764757,
       -0.008621571065665, -0.008621571065665, -0.008653624512661,
       -0.008653624512661, -0.008685593405662, -0.008717484044583,
       -0.008717484044583, -0.00874930272934 , -0.008781055759851,
       -0.008781055759851, -0.008844390057794, -0.008875983925059,
       -0.008907537337741, -0.008939056595756, -0.009002017847451,
       -0.009064918079472, -0.009159264264146, -0.009380267920972])
```

but `matplotlib` doesnt manage to plot it on a correct axis if I do

```
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(xGrid, results)
    plt.savefig('test.pdf')
```

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure matplotlib does not use longdouble internally and therefore all the beautiful precision is lost. You can plot with `plt.plot(xGrid - 1, results)` (or simply `plt.plot(results)`) and then adjust the tick labels on the x axis.

Comment: @kazemakase Where did you find that "matplotlib does not use longdouble internally"? I'm pretty sure this not to be the case (as matplotlib should simply use the numpy arrays as they are), but if you have any reference for that?!

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I don't have evidence, which "pretty sure" was meant to convey. Nor do I need evidence since your answer below obviously proves me wrong :) Thank you for correcting my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the precision of the values, but rather the default settings of the x axis locator. If you zoom into the plot you would see that the values are all there.
To show the desired range, one may set the viewing range manually: `plt.xlim(1-1e-14, 1)`. In order to get some useful ticklabels, setting up a `LinearLocator` with predefined number of ticks might be useful.

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker

xGrid =np.linspace(1-1e-14, 1-1e-16, 30, dtype=np.longdouble)
y = np.random.rand(len(xGrid))

plt.plot(xGrid, y)
plt.xlim(1-1e-14, 1)

loc = matplotlib.ticker.LinearLocator(numticks=5)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)

plt.show()
```

[image]